# What is the best practice using Android Logger

Tags: android, file, logging

I am new to Android. Please help me to know about the best practice of using Android Logger. Do I need to keep a file somewhere in android and keep on writing logs into it, or writing of logs into file is not necessary. What could be the best practice.

My real intention is this.
Once we go live, if our customers come back and tell us that something crashed or does not work in their android , then how do we debug ?
In the web application, I would ask my server administrator to provide the log files. What do we do with the android application when there is no server error, but something failed in the phone. Is there a way to get logs from the phone.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: One important thing to note-  android's Log class writes to a shared log.  Use it all you want in debugging, but in the release build don't print out anything not absolutely necessary-  it just makes it harder for the rest of us to use when you're spamming it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to publish/distribute your application then storing logs in a file is possible but as per my opinion better not a better solution. You can configure online tools from your app.

Catch all sever exceptions and sending all the details regarding that exception. And configure any one logging tool into you application.

You can see log4j http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/ or ACRA http://acra.ch/ or http://www.crittercism.com/

Comment: Sure its feasible, we've been doing it for 50 years.

Comment: @GabeSechan If you are storing in a file for every mobile then how to you gather all the reports for all the mobile? You tell them to send it via mail? And you keep on incrementing the file numbers? I think the better approach is to use such online tools available in market they are there for the same reason and dont consume mobile space and no additional logic required for file writing.

Comment: If there's a user with a particular problem, you have them send you the log.  You don't need or want the vast, vast, vast majority of logs.  Even attempting to do so just generates a lot of data that you'll never look at-  because there's so much data you're looking for needles in haystacks.  At most maybe there's a point to uploading crashes-  but even then if you have any QA at all it isn't going to find much.

Comment: Well it depends on the requirement i would say.

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't say so.  Logging everything that everyone does and uploading it is only useful if you actually manage to use that data to improve the program.  If you can't, it actually makes your program more fragile.  I won't say that nobody manages to do that, but I'll say that the places that do are in the minority.  And that's ignoring the privacy aspect of things-  its just creepy to do.  I wouldn't use an app that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need, you need logging for semi debugging your application than you can easily use the buildin Log functionality. Via Logcat you can easiliy see the logs.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html

```
//Declare a tag
String TAG= "SomeActivity";

//Log
Log.d(TAG, "Hello World"); //debug
Log.e(TAG, "Hello World"); //error
```

If you want to have logging of multiple devices when you have released your app. Use a dedicated Log Framework (e.g. Log4J) and upload it to a server.

Comment: My real intention is this.
Once we go live, if our customers come back and tell us that something crashed or does not work in their android , then how do we debug ?
In the web application, I would ask my server administrator to provide the log files. What do we do with the android application when there is no server error, but something failed in the phone. Is there a way to get logs from the phone.

Comment: It is in my answer: use a dedicated Log Framework such as Log4J and upload it to a server.

Answer (score 0):

The Android logger's (`android.util.Log`) output goes to a console that you don't have to maintain. You don't actually have to manage files, just outputs.

You have 5 categories of log:

- verbose: use `Log.v(tag, message)`
- debug: use `Log.d(tag, message)`
- info: use `Log.i(tag, message)`
- warning: use `Log.w(tag, message)`
- error: use `Log.e(tag, message)`

For example:

```
Log.e("MyActivity", "Oops... caught this exception: " + exception.getMessage());
```

The LogCat console (this is its name) allows you filtering by log level. This is a ceil filtering. For example, if you filter by 'warnings', you will see all warnings and errors, but not verbose, debug and info messages.

You'll find more details here in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Answer (score 0):

One tip (if you are using Eclipse, and not directly related to question) - Eclipse is very unreliable for viewing logs. For apparently no reason it completely stops displaying logs every now and then. A simple solution is to use command line tools for viewing logs. On Linux you can do :

```
$adb logcat MyTag:D *:S
```

If you want to capture logs to a file you can do:

```
$adb logcat -d > logcat.txt.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use file for storage logs - it possible problem with performance if the file become big. So you need clean file in time.
As for me best solution use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) or https://fabric.io/.
We use fabric.io. 
Also you can use some wrapper for default Log class. This one https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo for example